# Создать список словарей

Tags: python

Имеется набор чисел такого вида:

```
1518 1707
1518 1525
1518 1511
1518 1246
1707 1518
1707 1700
1707 1980
1525 1518
1525 1700
1525 1532
1525 1239
```

и.т.д.

Как видите, слева числа повторяются.
Нужно из этого создать список словарей такого вида:

```
[
{1518:[1707,1525,1511,1246]},
{1707:[1518,1700,1980]},
{1525:[1518,1700,1532,1239]},

.........

]
```

и т.д.
Как это сделать? Python
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````py
# Входные данные
>>> src = """1518 1707
...
... 1518 1525
...
... 1518 1511
...
... 1518 1246
...
... 1707 1518
...
... 1707 1700
...
... 1707 1980
...
... 1525 1518
...
... 1525 1700
...
... 1525 1532
...
... 1525 1239"""
>>> src = (tuple(map(int, line.split())) for line in filter(len, src.split("\n")))  # Приведение к удобному виду
>>> result = {}  # Где будет результат
>>> for key, val in src:  # Формирование результата
...     if key in result:
...             result[key].append(val)
...     else:
...             result[key] = [val]
...
>>> result
{1518: [1707, 1525, 1511, 1246], 1707: [1518, 1700, 1980], 1525: [1518, 1700, 1532, 1239]}
>>> result = [{key: val} for key, val in result.items()]  # Приведение к необходимому виду
>>> result
[{1518: [1707, 1525, 1511, 1246]}, {1707: [1518, 1700, 1980]}, {1525: [1518, 1700, 1532, 1239]}]```
````